# Nginx rewrite rule "^/([a-z0-9]{32})\.png$" not working (used to work on Apache)

Tags: nginx, configuration, rewrite, virtualhost

I have these rewrite rules (I tried both with no avail):

```
location ~* "^/([a-z0-9]{32})\.png$" {
  rewrite ^ /index.php?page=log&id=$1 last;
}
```

and

```
location ~* "/(?<hash>[a-z0-9]{32})\.png" {
  rewrite ^ /index.php?page=log&id=$hash;
}
```

and

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
}

location @rewrites {
  rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})\.png$" /index.php?page=log&id=$1 last;
  #...
}
```

Basically, I want the URL `http://example.com/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.png` to actually pass the parameters to my `index.php` script, and in the script, I got:

```php
$db->save_hash($_GET['id']);
header('Content-type: image/png');
readfile('images/beacon.png');
break;
```

But nginx is giving me a "not found", but other rewrites work fine. What gives?

Comment: i'm using nginx 1.2.1 on ubuntu 12.10

Comment: I can confirm the first method by unlo works. Could you post your error logs and the context in which you put the rewrite?

Comment: for example this is a recent one `2013/01/17 15:21:31 [error] 3276#0: *20993 open() "/var/www/site/b14ad9f3b159f58e4f559662c12d9dcd.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: site, request: "GET /b14ad9f3b159f58e4f559662c12d9dcd.png HTTP/1.1", host: "site", referrer: "http://sn132w.snt132.mail.live.com/..."` nothing else, no errors. The rewrite is inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site` nothing special

Comment: From seeing that I can only tell that the rewrite is either never reached or is completely ignored. Do you have breaks elsewhere, perhaps in a .png$ location?

Comment: nope, that's my only rewrite with pngs. every other rewrite, url based, are below this one, so it wouldn't matter, is there any way I debug all the rewrites that happen, in order, and dump to a file?

Comment: [rewrite_log](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite_log) should give you some basic info. If possible, I would also try making a completely blank server config with just that rewrite, just to make sure that the rewrite itself is the problem.

Comment: The docs for "location" make it clear that file order isn't the only consideration. If you have other location rules that might match the same content, then a rule like `"location /"` or `"location ^~ ..."` could step in and cause all your regular expression based rules to be skipped. Even if those rules at at the end of the config file, they are executed first in the web engine. See: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: I'm using html 5 boilerplate nginx config for mime types and expires, but there are no rewrites in there.

Comment: If you take your rewrite out, and put a real image file like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.png" in the site directory, does it serve the file to you directly?  If so, what happens when you put the rewrite back in the config? If not, then your issue is greater than a regex problem.

Comment: the file gets rendered fine =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per nginx documentation of how the [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) directive works:

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression. 
>   ...
>   A search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used.

Based on addition information [from your own answer](https://serverfault.com/a/471867/151339) to this very question, it would seem like you intend on having several location directives to apply simultaneously right at the very same time, which is explicitly not allowed as per the unambiguous documentation.

Remember, nginx is faster and cleaner by design.  So, don't expect the quirks!

Comment: I see, I thought they would 'cascade', so it would work somehow like apache... thanks for clearing that out!

Answer (score 4):

this one worked for me:

```
    location / { 
    rewrite "/([a-z0-9]{32})\.png" /index.php?page=log&id=$1 break;
    }
```

Or if you want separeted location:

```
location ~* "/([a-z0-9]{32})\.png" {
rewrite /(.*) /index.php?page=log&id=$1 last;
}
```

Comment: didn't work, same 404 error

Comment: could you post all nginx conf? i think you have a more detailed location, which can match request even if its located below rewrite rule...

Comment: i enabled rewrite_log in the config, but the regexp isn't even showing there... it's going directly to error.log,  failed `(2: No such file or directory)`

Comment: see if you can fix my answer http://serverfault.com/a/471867/151339

Comment: So, you have much preferred location in expires.conf: # Media: \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$.  And i think, include of h5bp located before redirect rule, am i right?  You must place our rule before include or remove png from expires.conf location.

Comment: it didn't work moving the .conf include after the rewrites... I guess I'll have to live without it until theres a fix. I've notified them on github repo about it

Answer (score 0):

While @unlo's answer seems correct to me (tried myself on a clean virtualhost), I see one more optimisation. Instead of serving a static file by your script, you may want to use [XSendFile](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) feature to make nginx serve these files.

Comment: how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Mark pointed out so I started removing all the included files, and boiled down to:

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/h5bp.conf`

that contains

```
# Basic h5bp rules

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/expires.conf;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/x-ua-compatible.conf;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/protect-system-files.conf;
```

the `expires.conf` got

```
# Expire rules for static content

# No default expire rule. This config mirrors that of apache as outlined in the
# html5-boilerplate .htaccess file. However, nginx applies rules by location,
# the apache rules are defined by type. A concequence of this difference is that
# if you use no file extension in the url and serve html, with apache you get an
# expire time of 0s, with nginx you'd get an expire header of one month in the
# future (if the default expire rule is 1 month). Therefore, do not use a
# default expire rule with nginx unless your site is completely static

# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html|xml|json)$ {
  expires -1;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/static.log;
}

# Feed
location ~* \.(?:rss|atom)$ {
  expires 1h;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Favicon
location ~* \.ico$ {
  expires 1w;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# Media: images, video, audio, HTC
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# CSS and Javascript
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
  expires 1y;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

# WebFonts
# If you are NOT using cross-domain-fonts.conf, uncomment the following directive
location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

commenting that `expires.conf`, then it starts working, how can I fix this?